# How can I git push to aws cloud9?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I have aws cloud environment, how can I push code from my local pc to environment?
It's hard to copy and paste code manually.

Comment: Do you want to simply copy files, or do you want to go via a `git` repository?

Comment: git repository? Is it github repository? no I just want push from my local pc

Comment: What do you mean by "push"? In your question title you mention "git push", which suggests the need for a git repository somewhere. Or, do you just want to upload the files without involving git?

Comment: basically I'm looking for best way to push my code to aws cloud9 from local pc, I had expirience with "git" when I was using github so thats why I thought I can also use "git" for it, by git repository you mean when u typing "git init"?

Comment: So by "push" I mean command promt way to get my code from local pc to aws cloud9 environment.

Comment: I did some research and I think I prefer to use git so I can see that files been updated, so I have to commit them first then push

Comment: If you want to use git, you would push from your computer to whatever repository you are using. Then, in Cloud9, you would open a terminal window and use `git clone` to get a copy on the Cloud9 server. If you just want to upload the files from your computer, then I think you can just drag the files (or folder) into the file listing in the Cloud9 window in your web browser.

Comment: problem is what Im updating it almost everyday so it's annoying to open cloud9 environment every time I update something

Answer (score 2):

You would need to [Integrate AWS Cloud9 with AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ide-c9.html)

Then you would be able to:

- define a [create a new Git repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-create-repository.html) with AWS CLI
- [clone it locally](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-connect.html)

  ```
  git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyDemoRepo my-demo-repo
  ```

Comment: I'll try that, is where any guide I can follow?

Comment: @pekaP I would start with the links I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: So I did every step but how would I restart my node app after u pushed something from my pc?

Comment: I want to use aws cloud9 as a hosting not IDE

Comment: @DNLST Maybe (not tested) through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda.html

Comment: @VonC I tried same thing as u send DNLST but I can't figure out what does it have to do with aws cloud9

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I can use `git` command in lambda function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381918/how-do-i-install-git-using-aws-lambda, but when I can't clone repo from codecommit